# JavaScript: .push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, array, canvas, push

¿qué tal? 
Estoy practicando algo de JavaScript, ya que soy nuevo con él, y estoy intentando crear un juego tipo "space invaders" con p5.js. He hecho algo de avance, pero, me he encontrado con un problema que no puedo resolver:

```
var ship;
var aliens = []; 
var missiles = [];
...
...
function keyPressed() {
if (key === ' ') {
    var missiles = new missile (width/2, height/2);
    missiles.push(missile)
```

Cuando intento probar pulsando la barra espaciadora, me dice lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que al presionar la barra espaciadora, el código añada un nuevo elemento al array missiles, pero, ¿por qué arroja ese error?

Comment: Tienes la variable missiles declarada dos veces.

Comment: con `var missiles = new missile` ya no es un array, por eso no tiene push

Comment: Eso era, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COn esto deberia de solucionarse tu inconveniente, teniendo en cuenta que solo quieres agregar esos parametros al array previamente definido:

```
var ship;
var aliens = []; 
var missiles2 = [];
...
...
function keyPressed() {
if (key === ' ') {
   
  //creamos el objeto que deseas con sus parametros
   var obj = new missile (width/2, height/2);
  //agregamos el objeto al array
   missiles2.push('obj');

}
```

mas info. [Metodo Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push)

espero te sirva y la marques XD... ReNiceCode....

Comment: Hola, srJJ, gracias por tu comentario. Creo que debí añadir más información respecto al código. Con missiles.push, quería añadir al array un objeto missile que acepta dos parámetros como su ubicación (x, y), y esos dos parámetros son width/2, height/2. Lo que no entiendo es por qúe me dice que missiles.push no es una función si missiles es un array y .push es para arrays :/

Comment: debido a que aparentemente una instancia de una clase que recibe dos parametros `= new missile (width/2, height/2);` entonces ya esa varaible la deja de reconocer como array, por ende el metodo `push` ya no existe.

Comment: mira, ya edite la respuesta @JoseA.Pacheco, creo que esto es lo que necesitas

Comment: Sos un crack, me funcionó. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: de nada Bro.. me alegro mucho haberte ayudado :)